# How to read a csv using sql

Tags: python, sql, csv, python-3.x

I would like to know how to read a csv file using sql. I would like to use group by and join other csv files together. How would i go about this in python.

example:

```
select * from csvfile.csv where name LIKE 'name%'
```

Comment: sql? python? Which is it? What's your specific problem at hand?

Comment: I would like to use sql to query a csv file. select * from csvfile.csv where name LIKE 'name%'

Comment: SQL is used for quering databases not text files. First create your schema/tables in a database of your choice, then load with python the csv values inside your db tables. Finally you make your queries with SQL.

Comment: There's no reason in theory that SQL cannot be applied to CSV files and, in fact, there are SQL engines that store data in CSV format. A quick search did not turn up any for Python, however.

Comment: Not sure why this was placed on hold.  It's quite clear what's being asked -- how to query csv files with SQL statements.  The fact that it's not possible to do so using only Python indicates only a hole in the OP's knowledge, not a lack of clarity.

Answer (score 2):

SQL code is executed by a database engine.  Python does not directly understand or execute SQL statements.

While some SQL database store their data in csv-like files, almost all of them use more complicated file structures.  Therefore, you're required to import each csv file into a separate table in the SQL database engine.  You can then use Python to connect to the SQL engine and send it SQL statements (such as SELECT).  The engine will perform the SQL, extract the results from its data files, and return them to your Python program.

The most common lightweight engine is SQLite.

Answer (score 2):

[littletable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/littletable/) is a Python module I wrote for working with lists of objects as if they were database tables, but using a relational-like API, not actual SQL select statements. Tables in littletable can easily read and write from CSV files. One of the features I especially like is that every query from a littletable Table returns a new Table, so you don't have to learn different interfaces for Table vs. RecordSet, for instance. Tables are iterable like lists, but they can also be selected, indexed, joined, and pivoted - see [the opening page of the docs](http://pythonhosted.org/littletable/).

```
# print a particular customer name 
# (unique indexes will return a single item; non-unique
# indexes will return a Table of all matching items)
print(customers.by.id["0030"].name)
print(len(customers.by.zipcode["12345"]))

# print all items sold by the pound
for item in catalog.where(unitofmeas="LB"):
    print(item.sku, item.descr)

# print all items that cost more than 10
for item in catalog.where(lambda o : o.unitprice>10):
   print(item.sku, item.descr, item.unitprice)

# join tables to create queryable wishlists collection
wishlists = customers.join_on("id") + wishitems.join_on("custid") + catalog.join_on("sku")

# print all wishlist items with price > 10
bigticketitems = wishlists().where(lambda ob : ob.unitprice > 10)
for item in bigticketitems:
   print(item)
```

Columns of Tables are inferred from the attributes of the objects added to the table. namedtuples are good also, as well as a types.SimpleNamespaces. You can insert dicts into a Table, and they will be converted to SimpleNamespaces.

littletable takes a little getting used to, but it sounds like you are already thinking along a similar line.

Answer (score -2):

You can easily query an SQL Database using PHP script. PHP runs serverside, so all your code will have to be on a webserver (the one with the database). You could make a function to connect to the database like this:

```
$con= mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("An error has occured");
```

Then use the `$con` to accomplish other tasks such as looping through data and creating a table, or even adding rows and columns to an existing table.

EDIT: I noticed you said .CSV file. You can upload a CSV file into a SQL database and create a table out of it. If you are using a control panel service such as phpMyAdmin, you can simply import a CSV file into your database like this:

[image: PHPMyAdmin screenshot]

If you are looking for a free web host to test your SQL and PHP files on, check out [x10](http://x10hosting.com/) hosting.

Comment: This question is about Python, not PHP.  There's no indication in the question that a web server is involved in any way.  The user does not have a database running, but rather csv files.  Also, I'm certain that PHP offers parameterized queries so if this *were* a question about querying MySQL from a web server written in PHP, the part about SQL injection is not correct (assuming you coded carefully).  Also, there's no requirement for the database server to reside with the web server.